# Is there a way for a Discord bot to make an embedded message which has "slides"?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Basically, I am making a bot that displays RSOs at my university based on user input. So let's say I find RSOs A, B and C. I want to make the message cleaner, instead of just being a wall of text, so I was thinking of making an embedded message, where you can press on a "next" button to go through the different RSOs. I think I understand how to do a simple embedded message, but how can I do a more complex one?

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to make:

[image]

Comment: You can use interactions or use reactions to edit the message to give the appearance of "slides"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out how to do this, I used something called [paginator](https://github.com/interactions-py/paginator), which has this feature added into it. I also used interactions.py though to help with this, rather than discord.py.